# Robot Framework - Extract text from region after image match

Tags: robotframework, sikuli, rpa

In the attached image, I would like to extract the text available right after the image using the Robot Framework.  In the table, column 1 contains all images and column 2 contains the actual text(not image).  I would like to understand how can we extract the text available right after the image.  For example, I want to extract the text 'Solon' available against the image 'City'.  Similarly, '44139' available against the image 'Zip code'.  Can you please guide me on how can we do this using Robot Framework and Sikuli library.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had similar challenge and I wrote a custom library in python and imported to robot

Using tesseract and opencv you can do
First take image screen shot by specifying th coordinates then using tesseract convert image to text and store that in variables

Comment: This would be better suited as a comment, since it's just a general suggestion. Take a look again at [answer]